# Teradata 14: Add seconds to timestamp

Tags: timestamp, teradata

In Teradata 14 I want to add 1 second in timestamp format.
Say,
Previous timestamp was '2017-05-02 08:27:42.680000'
After adding a second it should be '2017-05-02 08:27:42.690000'.

I tried using below query and it works in Teradata 15.10 but not in Bteq and throws an Syntax error.

```
SELECT *timestampfield* + INTERVAL '0.01' SECOND  AS NEW_TIMESTAMP
FROM *tablename*;
```

Can someone help me on this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: By Teradata 15.10, are you referring to Teradata Studio? What if you try adding 1 second to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in BTEQ using the same syntax without the FROM clause? `SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL '0.01 SECOND AS New_Timestamp;`

Comment: What error are you getting? Your syntax as above looks good to me. Except that if you are really trying to add 1 second it should be `INTERVAL '1' SECOND'`.